# fetching the data from HTML <Tags> in to iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad

Can any one let me know the simple way to fetch the HTML data from url into my app. also please refer me some tutorial, if any?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://mobiletraining.mcs.schoolinsites.com/?PageName=LatestNews&Section=Highlights&It%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BemID=114932&ISrc=School&Itype=Highlights&SchoolID=172%0A%09%09"];
NSURL *tutorialsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:tutorialsUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"Your Html >> %@",htmlString);
```

Comment: hey can i get the only dir i want in the html?

Comment: like a particular < dir > of entire HTML

Comment: you can get your data using string length and position functionality

Answer (score -2):

You can get the HTML data by reading the data of the url into an NSData object like so

```
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:htmlURL];
```

or as an NSString like

```
NSError *error=nil; 
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:htmlURL] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Comment: NSString* str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",self.urlN];
    NSURL *tutorialsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tutorialsUrl];

Comment: in the above case, you will need to convert the nsdata to a readable string via encoding like `NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`, also you may try the second part of code posted in my answer and NSLog it to see if it prints the contents of the html.

Comment: can you post the url you are trying to get the data of?

Comment: "mobiletraining.mcs.schoolinsites.com/?PageName=LatestNews&Section=Highlights&ItemID=114932&ISrc=School&Itype=Highlights&SchoolID=172%0A%09%09

Comment: if the url is working now & my answer has helped you, please consider upvoting & accepting my answer.